# If Else statement Powershell CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, if-statement

When I run my code, it gives me the following error. [image: Error]
What I am having the code do is taking the csv then filtering the name column to only be administrators, then I am having the caption column filter all of the operating systems that I have provided. The if statement is saying that If the column Type0 equals domain then put in the "Unique Account Name" column the Domain0 following the Account0. Else it will put it in Netbios name and then Account0. Below will be the excel sheet. and the desired output of each.
[image: Excel Sheet]
[image: Desired output of Unique Account Name]

```
 Import-Csv 'U:\Local Group Members.csv' | where-Object {($_.Name0 -eq "administrators") -and ($_.caption0 -match "Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise|Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise|Microsoft Windows 7 Professional|Microsoft Windows 8 Enterprise|Microsoft Windows 8 Pro|Microsoft Windows 8.1 Enterprise|Microsoft Windows 8.1 Pro")} |
Select-Object "Netbios_name0", "Name0", "Account0","category0","Domain0","Unique Account Name","Type0","caption0", "Excluded" |
ForEach-Object 

If ($_.Type0 -eq 'Domain') { 
    $_.UniqueAccountName = "$($_.Domain0) - $($_.Account0)" 
} Else { 
    $_.UniqueAccountName = "$($_.Netbios_name0) - $($_.Account0)" 
}

Export-Csv -notypeinformation U:\LGMbestone.csv
```

I am a powershell Novice, and I am stuck, and how do I can I get this code to run?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If statement CSV Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44528728/if-statement-csv-powershell)

Comment: It seems unlikely that repeatedly asking the same question multiple times without sufficient detail isn't going to get you an answer.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart does this one not give more detail than the other one?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart This one is a different question. This one is about the Unique Account Name.

Comment: It's very, very close to the same thing.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart does this one not give a clearer image of what I am trying to do?

Comment: You can't pipe to `if`. Why did you remove the foreach? You don't send anything to export-csv either

Comment: Right. Iterate using foreach and then use the if else inside the loop and append the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't pipe to an if statement, and you're going to need to iterate through the result line by line to modify the object, which calls for a foreach loop. Also, piping to Export-CSV is better than calling it with an input object. An example based on your code is below. Hope this helps!

```
    $csv = Import-Csv 'U:\Local Group Members.csv' |
Where-Object {($_.Name0 -eq "administrators") -and ($_.caption0 -match "Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise|Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise|Microsoft Windows 7 Professional|Microsoft Windows 8 Enterprise|Microsoft Windows 8 Pro|Microsoft Windows 8.1 Enterprise|Microsoft Windows 8.1 Pro")} |
Select-Object "Netbios_name0", "Name0", "Account0","category0","Domain0","Unique Account Name","Type0","caption0", "Excluded"

#Modify each line based on your parameters
Foreach ($row in $csv) {
    If ($row.Type0 -eq 'Domain') { 
        $row."Unique Account Name" = "$($row.Domain0) - $($row.Account0)" 
        Write-Host $row."Unique Account Name"
    } Else { 
        $row."Unique Account Name" = "$($row.Netbios_name0) - $($row.Account0)"
    }
}

#Export CSV
$csv | Export-Csv C:\LGMbestone.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: I ran that code and it ran all for me except it did not give me the export of the csv

Comment: That seemed to work after i switched the path. But now The code works only for the 'Domain' part.

Comment: @Sprengdilly Try changing `$row."Unique Account Name"` to `$row.UniqueAccountName`.

It has to match the column name in the CSV, so if there are no spaces in the CSV, remove the spaces in the script. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not help, The Domain part worked as I stated before, so I do not believe it has anything to do with the "Unique Account Name"

Comment: I double checked all of the spelling to on everything and it still appears to not work on the Local ones. Would doing another if statement be able to fix this problem?

Comment: My bad, I didn't understand your statement before. Looks like the script I posted still has some of your old code in it, right where the 'local' side of things does business. Hang on a sec and I'll edit that.

Comment: @Sprengdilly, try the edited script above. It was still referencing the pipeline (`$_`) rather than the variable (`$row`)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146683/discussion-between-deprofundis-and-sprengdilly).

Answer (score 0):

looks like one formatting issue. With foreach , it should be something like this:

```
$import=Import-Csv 'U:\Local Group Members.csv' | where-Object {($_.Name0 -eq "administrators") -and ($_.caption0 -match "Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise|Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise|Microsoft Windows 7 Professional|Microsoft Windows 8 Enterprise|Microsoft Windows 8 Pro|Microsoft Windows 8.1 Enterprise|Microsoft Windows 8.1 Pro")} |
Select-Object "Netbios_name0", "Name0", "Account0","category0","Domain0","Unique Account Name","Type0","caption0", "Excluded" 

ForEach($imp in $import)
{ 

    If ($imp.Type0 -eq 'Domain') 
    { 
        $imp.UniqueAccountName = "$($imp.Domain0) - $($imp.Account0)" 
    } 
    Else 
    { 
        $imp.UniqueAccountName = "$($imp.Netbios_name0) - $($imp.Account0)" 
    }

    Export-Csv "$imp.UniqueAccountName" -notypeinformation "U:\LGMbestone.csv" -Append
}
```

Note: I have not checked the import-csv part. I believe its properly taking the data and you should use foreach loop for iterating each row value

Comment: You can't pipe to `if`.

Comment: typo :).removing it

Comment: @RanadipDutta can you show what you mean by using the foreach loop and iterating each row value?

Comment: @RanadipDutta this is probably a stupid question but what is the  -append for at the end of the code?

Comment: -Append is used for appending the data in the file. Example: YOu have already data1 in a file. And you want to add data2 to your file keeping the data1. Thats appending. So in this case, each data whatever coming out of the loop is getting appended (adding the additional values each time instead of replacing the file)throughout the loop.

Comment: @RanadipDutta Whenever I run your code, it does not export the csv file

Comment: Are you having the value in `$imp.UniqueAccountName`?? give a write-output and see the value is there or not